# How to wrap an UDP connection to improve resistance agains packet loss?

Tags: networking, udp, redundancy

Suppose there is UDP connection that does not expect much packet loss.

Are there already tools that allow wrapping a UDP connection to gain more reliability at expence of bandwidth and overhead, for example, using Reed-Solomon codes.

Expected usage:

```
host1$ someprogram --listen-udp 127.0.0.1:1234
host1$ reedsolomon_udp --listen 0.0.0.0:1235 --connect 127.0.0.1:1234

host2$ reedsolomon_udp --connect host1:1235 --listen 127.0.0.1:1234
host2$ someprogram --connect-udp 127.0.0.1:1234
```

The solution is not expected to remove losses outright, it expected to reduce them, especially if more than 50% packets are getting lost.

Comment: There have been some papers written on this, but I've never seen an actual implementation: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6865 and http://www.mai.ru/science/trudy/eng/published.php?ID=14801&eng=Y which is unfortunately just an abstract

Answer (score 2):

If the program expects reliable connections, then it needs to use TCP, not UDP. UDP is unprotected against loss at the protocol level - it's a best-effort delivery system only. TCP is a guaranteed-delivery system.

Comment: UDP program can expect some loss, for example, about 2%. And actual loss can be, for example, 70%. I need to "hammer thought" very unreliable network. The progam in question is not expected to remove the losses, it expected to lessen the number of them.

Comment: Actually there is going to be TCP inside the UDP tunnel. But TCP works bad when many packets are getting lost. I'm considering implementing "reedsolomon_udp" myself, but first asking here because of maybe someone somewhere for something already implemented such thing.

Comment: TCP inside a UDP tunnel? You're asking for problems. If you need to reduce packet loss, you need to clean up the dirty network. Wrapping a TCP connection inside a UDP "tunnel" (there really is no such thing), and then trying to re-wrap it to reduce packet loss, will very rapidly get you to an infinite-wait state due to the exponential back-off properties of the TCP session.

Comment: I want this as a solution to "clean up dirty network" that I can't control (as workaround).

And what's wrong with "TCP inside UDP tunnel"? It's not TCP inside TCP. For example, Teredo uses this and doesn't seem to trouble...

Comment: What you want doesn't exist. TCP inside UDP is bad. Teredo is for IPv6-inside-IPv4, which is at a different layer of the protocol stack, so it doesn't really apply. You're stuck. Clean up the network, or have it cleaned up, or deal with the packet loss. Those are your only practical choices.

Comment: It will be TCP inside TUN/TAP inside UDP. `Clean up the network` -> not always possible. `What you want doesn't exist.` -> OK. I just don't like to discover after a while that a program was actually already written (but I didn't known about that).

Comment: Implementing an application level reliability protocol over UDP sometimes performs better than TCP. TCP suffers greatly from small amounts of packet loss because the entire stream is held up while retransmit timers expire to resend lost packets, the window is often filled during this period and so you get a huger performance penalty. Implementing forward error correction allows you to tolerate a small amount of packet loss and potentially obtain a higher level of performance. Of course such an implementation that handles everything TCP does would be very challenging.

Comment: TCP's performance problems come from ordered stream. OP didn't ask for ordered, just reliability of losslessness.

Answer (score 0):

ARQ is the name of a family of methods, one variety of which is used by TCP.
Some varieties are sometimes used to "wrap" UDP.

For example, in video streaming, UDP may be used to avoid the overhead of TCP.
A variety of ARQ is used in some cases to add some reliability for an MPEG Transport Stream carrying video over the internet.
Such a variety of ARQ is intended to create lower overhead than TCP,
while still allowing for increasing the reliability of receiving of the video stream.

See this wikipedia article for a fuller discussion and list of references:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_repeat_request